# roc_curve from multilabel classification has slope

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, roc

I have a multilabel classifier written in Keras from which I want to compute AUC and plot a ROC curve for every element classified from my test set.

[image]

Everything seems fine, except that some elements  have a roc curve that have a slope as follows:

[image]

I don't know how to interpret the slope in such cases.

Basically my workflow goes as follows, I have a pre-trained `model`, instance of Keras, and I have the features `X` and the binarized labels `y`, every element in `y` is an array of length 1000, as it is a multilabel classification problem each element in `y` might contain many 1s, indicating that the element belongs to multiples classes, so I used the built-in loss of `binary_crossentropy` and my outputs of the model prediction are score probailities. Then I plot the roc curve as follows.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
#...
for xi, yi in (X_test, y_test):
    y_pred = model.predict([xi])[0]
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(yi, y_pred)

    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=0.5)
```

The predict method returns probabilities, as I'm using the functional api of keras.

Does anyone knows why roc curves looks like this?

Comment: You may want to look at roc_auc_score (here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) instead of roc_curve, as the latter may not be appropriate for a multilabel setting; the former specifically says multilabel is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking in the mailing list of scikit-learn, they answered:

> Slope usually means there are ties in your predictions.

Which is the case in this problem.